# NSURLConnection not responding after making the request

Tags: ios, web-services, nsurlconnection

I have written the following code to get data from a web service:

```
- (void)fetchOnlineUserList
{
    NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s",ServerPath,URLUserList];
    NSMutableURLRequest *updateRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]
                                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                             timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [updateRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"userid=%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"user_id"]];
    [updateRequest setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [updateRequest setValue:@"" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];
    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]
                                    initWithRequest:updateRequest
                                    delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

    [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
                          forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    webData = [NSMutableData data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [webData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //Process data
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //Connection failed
}
```

But the problem is, most of the times this works well, sometimes it is not. Not working in the sense, it is not triggering any delegate methods, not even the connection failure. But at times, it works perfectly. What can be the issue here? I have so many web requests in my app, and only a few web services are showing this strange error most of the times. And mostly it will work perfectly in simulator. In the above code, I am running the connection in the main thread. Preaviously I was making the request using `[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:updateRequest delegate:self]`, but then I came across this issue and many answers in stackoverflow told me run the connection in main thread and so I changed my code like this.

Comment: May i know why you changed your code to run in the main thread?, because the way generally it is preferred to make asynchronous request using [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:updateRequest delegate:self]

Comment: The same issue, I had the same issue when I tried to run it that way. and then i saw some answers in SO asking me run in main thread, but it didnt help me either

Comment: I tried your code, and in my case delegate methods are being called all the time. Sometimes the web api takes time to load, but still delegate methods are being called.